# Grab all YouTube links from a channel

Tags: youtube-api

the following link grabs youtube videos in JSON format but it only seems to be grabbing 66 videos out of 500~ total videos

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/EEVblog/uploads?alt=json

how would I grab all the video urls rather than just 66 (also its not 66 total because some are duplicates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using v3 of the Data API, but regardless...

You should use the start-index and max-results parameters with the gdata feed you listed above.

For example, this call:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/EEVblog/uploads?alt=json

Has an attribute called "next" with this value:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/EEVblog/uploads?alt=json&start-index=26&max-results=25

And the next call after that would be:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/EEVblog/uploads?alt=json&start-index=51&max-results=25

I'm getting far more than 66 results this way, its just displaying 25 at a time...